# Stacked line charts or streamgraphs in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, raphael, stacked-area-chart, stream-graph

Does anyone have any examples of stacked graphs (or stream graphs) in Raphael?

I'm wondering if there is a working Raphael equivalent of this [D3 streamgraph](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/stream.html):

[image]

The closest I've seen is [this line chart](http://raphaeljs.com/chart.html) example:

[image]

I guess I could just knock up a stacked graph based on this, but it'd be great if anyone already had some outline code.

Comment: does it have to be Raphael? cause [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked) are pretty powerful, and it's all JS...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://g.raphaeljs.com/). It's based on Raphael.

If you need something more powerful I could recommend [Sencha ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-3).
[Area Graph #1](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/charts/Area%20-%20BrowserStats.html) and [Area Graph #2](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/charts/Area.html) are looking quite like your posted D3 streamgraph.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using Flot - I was looking for IE8 support and Flot turned out to have working examples already: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/stacking.html